# incorrect data return from left join query

Tags: mysql, join

table: countries

### country_id | country_name

```
    1  | Usa
    2  | Canada
    3  | Russia
    4  | Japan
```

table: (many2many) country_services

### country_id  | service_id

```
    1   |    1
    1   |    2
    1   |    3
    1   |    4
    2   |    1
    2   |    2
    2   |    3
    3   |    1
```

table: services

### service_id | service_name

```
    1  | service1
    2  | service2
    3  | service3
    4  | service4
    5  | service5
    6  | service6
```

I'm tryin to get the next result:

### service_id | country_name                    | service_name

```
    1  | USA                             | service1
    2  | USA                             | service2
    3  | USA                             | service3
    4  | USA                             | service4
```

My query is

```
SELECT s.service_id
     , s.service_name
     , c.country_name 
  FROM services s
  LEFT 
  JOIN country_service cs
    ON cs.service_id = s.service_id 
   AND cs.country_id = 1 
  LEFT 
  JOIN countries c
    ON c.country_id = cs.country_id;
```

and it returns:

> ### service_id | service_name                    | service_name
>
> ```
>    1  | service1                        | USA
>    2  | service2                        | USA
>    3  | service3                        | USA
>    4  | service4                        | USA
>    5  | service5                        | null
>    6  | service6                        | null
> ```

please, help me to correct my query. thanks

Answer (score 0):

A LEFT OUTER JOIN will return ALL ROWS from the table specified on the left side of the query, along with matching rows from the table on the right side of the query.

To achieve the result you're seeking, you'll want to use an INNER JOIN instead:

```
SELECT services.service_id, services.service_name, countries.country_name 
FROM services 
INNER JOIN country_service 
ON services.service_id = country_service.service_id 
AND country_service.country_id =1 
INNER JOIN countries 
ON country_service.country_id = countries.country_id
```

Answer (score 0):

use `INNER JOIN` instead of `LEFT OUTER JOIN` .

take a look here how the [joins work](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html)

Answer (score 0):

Since you want specifically services from the USA you should change the joins to `INNER`:

```
SELECT services.service_id, services.service_name, countries.country_name 
FROM services 
INNER JOIN country_service ON services.service_id = country_service.service_id AND country_service.country_id =1 
INNER JOIN countries ON country_service.country_id = countries.country_id
```